# Popup on Selected Cell

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

I have datagridview with a panel that pops-up when a cell is selected using this code

```
Private Sub dgvPurchase_EditingControlShowing(sender As Object, e As   DataGridViewEditingControlShowingEventArgs) Handles dgvPurchase.EditingControlShowing
    pnlItem.Location = New Point(314, 234) 
    If pnlItem.Visible Then
        pnlItem.Visible = False
    Else
        pnlItem.Visible = True
    End If

End Sub
```

The problem is the panel pops-out whichever cell I click. I want the panel to be visible only when I click a cell of a particular column in the row not on all cells in the row.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the `CurrentCell.RowIndex` before doing anything...

```
 If dgvPurchase.CurrentCell.RowIndex = YOURROWINDEX Then
   pnlItem.Location = New Point(314, 234) 
   If pnlItem.Visible Then
      pnlItem.Visible = False
   Else
      pnlItem.Visible = True
   End If
 End If
```

Note: This ***is just one way***, there are a few other ways as well, but this should help you.

Also I noticed you haven't accepted any solutions given to you that helped. On that note, SO is for helping others fix problems. If an answer has helped please be kind and reward them back by checking the checkmark and voting.

**EDIT**

Per your comments you want a specific column not row...

```
      If dgvPurchase.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex = YOURCOLUMNINDEX
```

This event will only happen if it's the column you want.

Comment: Sorry for this late reply @Zaggler, I lost internet yesterday. I tried your solution and changed the `YOURROWINDEX` to 1 since its on the second column but nothing happens and my panel wont pop-up any more.

Comment: Well what row do you want it to happen on? You didn't mention that... You said particular row but didn't mention the row, just change the number to what row you need... I just realized you said column in your comment. If that's the case your question is wrong itself and missleading... Please edit it.

Comment: Please see updated answer since what you requested was changed.

Comment: I'ved edited the question. I want the panel to pop-up when I click the cell of a particular column in the row. sorry bout the mistake not my native language that's why its hard for me to express.

Comment: `I want the panel to pop-up when I click the cell of a particular column` did you not see my update in the answer?